# Cannot set up admins for facebook comments

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-comments

We're having a weird issue on our website with facebook comments. It looks like the facebook scraper is incorrectly parsing (at least one of) our web pages so that it isn't picking up on admins to moderate the comments.

If you go to this link:

http://www.beliefnet.com/Espanol/10-Atletas-olimpicos-mas-inspiradores.aspx

and view source, you'll see that we have the appropriate  tags in the head, including one for fb:admins. If I am logged into facebook on that account, I get no moderator options.

Running the page through facebook object debugger, I get an error that we have meta tags in the body. Specifically, this error:

```
Meta Tags In Body:  You have tags ouside of your . This is either because 
your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally
put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it 
before the tags are usable.
```

Looking at the scraped URL at the bottom of that page, I see what looks to be that facebook has 'reorganized' our html, and placed the meta tags from the head into the body.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? I thought that maybe we had some malformed html somewhere in the page that was throwing everything off, but I went through the html for that page and it looks good. Is there something else that i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem ultimately was that there was a `<noscript>...</noscript>` nested in the head, that was trying to include a tracking pixel for browsers without javascript enabled, as part of an ad service we use.

the issue should've been obvious looking at the output facebook gave us for 'how they see your page'. the body begins immediately after the script, but immediately before where the  tag starts. apparently the facebook parser freaks out when it sees an element in the head that should be in the body, so it immediately starts the body there.

... facebook output ...

```
        console.log(OAS);
    })();
</script><!-- End OAS Setup --><!-- Begin comScore Tag --><script>
      var _comscore = _comscore || [];
      _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "8428430" });
      (function() {
        var s = document.createElement("script"), el = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.async = true;
        s.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el);
      })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>

    </noscript>
    <!-- End comScore Tag -->
```

... our html ...

```
<head>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder id="OASHeader" runat="server" />

    <!-- Begin comScore Tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _comscore = _comscore || [];
      _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "8428430" });
      (function() {
        var s = document.createElement("script"), el = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.async = true;
        s.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el);
      })();
    </script>    
    <!-- End comScore Tag -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=2&c2=8428430&cv=2.0&cj=1" alt="" />
    </noscript>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    ....
    <body>
    ....
```

so in the future, invalid head elements could definitely be causing this problem.

Comment: Good find and follow-up post!

Answer (score 1):

Running your URL through validator.w3.org shows a few warning signs:

```
Line 77, Column 14: document type does not allow element "noscript" here; assuming missing "object" start-tag
Line 154, Column 699: document type does not allow element "meta" here
```

I was able to narrow down the (potential) issue to these lines in your page:

```
document.write('<a href="' + OAS.config.url + 'click_nx.ads/' + OAS.config.sitepage + '/1' + OAS.config.rns + '@' + OAS.config.listpos + '!' + pos + '?' + OAS.config.query + '" target=' + OAS.config.target + '>');
document.write('<img src="' + OAS.config.url + 'adstream_nx.ads/' + OAS.config.sitepage + '/1' + OAS.config.rns + '@' + OAS.config.listpos + '!' + pos + '?' + OAS.config.query + '" border=\"0\" /></a>');
```

These document.write() lines are also failing the w3.org validator:

```
Line 53, Column 197: character "+" is not allowed in the value of attribute "target"
```

Moreover, I think it's bad to use document.write() for DOM insertion (and because it can lead to blocking of page rendering). 
Can you change to using js objects and DOM manipulation?

After FB fetches your URL, it runs it through a DOM parser that is probably choking when it encounters those document.write() lines. The fact that those lines have an <a> element spanning two document.writes() is probably confusing the parser. And the parser probably thinks it has reached the <body> of the page, thus the 'Meta tags in body' error.

As a quick test, try putting the fb:admins meta tag above those document.write() lines. Though, I wouldn't be surprised if the parser still chokes, but it's worth a try.

To test your page's html source, I used the simple script provided in a comment at the end of this php.net page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

It produced errors:

```
Unexpected end tag : a in /home/dlee/tmp/tmp.html, line: 54
Unexpected end tag : head in /home/dlee/tmp/tmp.html, line: 183
htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag in /home/dlee/tmp/tmp.html, line: 184
```

Where tmp.html was the html of your page saved to a file.
Line 54 is the previously mentioned document.write() line.

Let me know if any of the above results in progress, and I will edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: thx for the advice, it actually put me on the right track. see my post for the answer.